# Finding the global extrema of a surface?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to figure out how to find the global extrema of the function surface shown below and can't seem to get answers that make any sense. I am using the FindMinimum and FindMaximum functions shown below, but no matter how big I make the ranges for x and y, I get answers that are close to the edge ranges for x and y and very small (close to 0) for z. When I graph these points as extrema, they don't seem to make sense for the surface.

Any advice on finding extrema?

```
Clear[f, x, y, surfaceplot]; 
f[x_, y_] = E^(-x^2 - y^2); 
surfaceplot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -4Pi, 4Pi}, {y, -4Pi, 4Pi}, AxesLabel ->   {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint->{-2Pi, 2Pi, 5.1225*10^-35}];
datapoint1 = FindMinimum[{f[x,y], -2Pi<x<2Pi, -2Pi<y<2Pi},{{x,-2Pi}, {y,-2Pi}}]
datapoint2 = FindMaximum[{f[x,y], -2Pi<x<2Pi, -2Pi<y<2Pi},{{x,2Pi}, {y,2Pi}}]
```

Comment: `Clear[f, x, y, surfaceplot];
f[x_, y_] := E^(-x^2 - y^2);
FindMaximum[{f[x, y], -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi, -2 Pi < y < 2 Pi}, {{x, 
   1}, {y, 1}}]`

Comment: @SarahMarkers As belisarius shows, you're starting your search very far from the center of your Gaussian, where the slope is essentially 0 (to machine precision).  Once you get a better starting place, you'll be fine.